# why is my (from example) shader appearing as black?

Tags: unity, shaders

I have the following (very simple) shader:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain
RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Result[id.xy] = float4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Here is the dispatcher code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SkyShaderDispatcher : MonoBehaviour {

    public ComputeShader shader;
    public RenderTexture output; 
    void Start(){
//      RenderTexture output = new RenderTexture(256,256,24);
//      output.enableRandomWrite = true;
//      output.Create();

    }
    void Update(){
        RunShader();
    }
    void RunShader()
    {
        int kernelHandle = shader.FindKernel("CSMain");
        shader.SetTexture(kernelHandle, "Result", output);
        shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 256/8, 256/8, 1);
    }
}
```

which is the default red shader (it makes the texture red).
However, when I put the texture in a material and give that to an object, then that results in the object being black. Anyone seeing what I'm doing wrong?
[image: sphere]
[image: mat]
[image: tex]

As the shader is the default example right now it should work suggesting that maybe something is wrong with the texture?

Edit:
Trying to fit the same code on a skybox also fails. I have changed the dispatcher code into:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class launchClouds : MonoBehaviour {

    public ComputeShader shader;
    private RenderTexture output; 
    void Start(){

    }
    void Update(){
        RunShader();
    }


    void RunShader()
    {
        int kernelHandle = shader.FindKernel("CSMain");
        RenderTexture output = new RenderTexture(256,256,24);
        output.enableRandomWrite = true;
        output.Create();
        Material mat = gameObject.GetComponent<Skybox>().material;
        mat.SetTexture("_FrontTex",output);
        mat.SetTexture("_BackTex",output);
        mat.SetTexture("_LeftTex",output);
        mat.SetTexture("_RightTex",output);
        mat.SetTexture("_UpTex",output);
        mat.SetTexture("_DownTex",output);
        shader.SetTexture(kernelHandle,
                          "Result", output);
        shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 256/8, 256/8, 1);
    }
}
```

but that turns the sky black rather then making the sky red. This is using unity 5 32 bits with DirectX11.

Comment: don't know much about unity but a couple of things about your compute:

You're assigning id.xy as float4, should it not be id.xyzw?
You have trailing semi-colons in your compute.

Comment: tried changing that but it didn't do anything.